# What is the Linux equivalent of the Windows registry?

Tags: terminal, settings, laptop, dvd

I have a DVD+-RW drive that has quit working. Apparently many users of this laptop model experience the same problem under windows and are required to edit the registry to correct the problem. So where should I look to make a similar edit?

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you edit your post with information regarding precisely what the Windows registry change was (and, if you know, what the effect of the change is).

Comment: Also, [Super User](http://www.superuser.com/) would be a better venue, since it has people who know hardware and people who know Windows, both of which could help figure out how to transpose the Windows fix.

Comment: @Steven D I started a discussion at meta about this. I'm opposed to editing it on principle, since one A has already recieved so many votes. http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/201/what-should-i-do-with-this-q-edit-or-repost-with-new-details

Comment: Very similar I have found one is dconf Editor. [dconf-tools ![Install dconf-tools](http://hostmar.co/software-small)](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools).
It also store the settings of interfaces and applications as windows registry do. Have a look on it for your specific problem.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Thankfully, there is no Linux equivalent of the Windows registry. Configuration is kept in (mostly) text files:

- The system configuration is in text files under `/etc`.
- The system state, which in Windows ends up mixed with configuration data, lives under `/var.`
- User configuration and state lives in “dot files”, i.e., files and directories whose name begins with a `.` in your home directory.

You can't simply transpose a registry edit to a configuration in another operating system: registry edits are completely Windows-specific. You'll have to understand what the registry edit is doing and transpose it to Linux. It's likely that you'll end up modifying a file under `/etc`, but there are too many potential candidates to list here (also, it might depend on your distribution).

Comment: Wow, this seems not to answer the question at all, and yet it has fourteen upvotes.

Comment: Well the problem is that there are two very different questions here. This answer very clearly answers the question posed in the title, but the body of the question implies that "the Linux equivalent of the Windows registry" isn't what the poster is really after.

Comment: this is what I thought to be the case upon asking the question. I suppose it's a deeper question as to where those files are exactly.

Comment: The first word "thankfully" helped gain my upvote.  ;)

Comment: @Gilles, The `var` philosophy is itself problematic in the age of dynamic scripting and hotswapping. It should be called `/coresys` and `/noncoresys`

Comment: In fact, while Linux itself does not have an equivalent of Windows registry, some graphical environments used in Linux do have something similar. For example GNOME configuration database (the one you edit with `gsettings` or graphical tool `dconf`) has a lot of similarity to Windows registry.

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent of the registry on Linux is Elektra but it is not very popular. Most software uses a configuration file located in the /etc directory.

https://www.libelektra.org/